# I've heard that LaTeX is Turing complete. Are there any programs written in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, turing-complete

It's possible to do interesting things with what would ordinarily be thought of as typesetting languages. For example, you can construct the Mandelbrot set [using postscript](http://warp.povusers.org/MandScripts/ps.html).

It is suggested in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18813/modular-arithmetic-in-latex) that LaTeX may be [Turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). This implies the ability to write arbitrary programs (although it may not be easy!). Does anyone know of any concrete example of such a program in LaTeX, which does something highly unusual with the language?

Comment: You know, I WAS going to have a weekend playing outside.  You know, one of those away from a computer weekends?  Then you go and post this question.  This is why I can't have nice things.

Comment: /d{def}def/u{dup}d[0 -185 u 0 300 u]concat/q 5e-3 d/m{mul}d/z{A u m B u
m}d/r{rlineto}d/X -2 q 1{d/Y -2 q 2{d/A 0 d/B 0 d 64 -1 1{/f exch d/B
A/A z sub X add d B 2 m m Y add d z add 4 gt{exit}if/f 64 d}for f 64 div
setgray X Y moveto 0 q neg u 0 0 q u 0 r r r r fill/Y}for/X}for showpage

Comment: Well… [An AVR Emulator written in pure LaTeX – Turing completeness!](https://gitlab.brokenpipe.de/stettberger/avremu/tree/master) 

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In issue 13 of [*The Monad Reader*](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf), Stephen Hicks writes about implementing the solution to an ICFP contest (involving Mars rover navigation) in TeX, with copious use of macros. Amusingly, the solution's output when typeset is a postscript map of the rover's path.

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, Andrew Greene wrote [a BASIC interpreter in TeX](https://web.archive.org/web/20120707000649/http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/basix.html) ([more details](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb11-3/tb29greene.pdf)).  This may count as slightly perverse.

Comment: Interpreter link is dead

Comment: Use Archive.org to see interpreter: https://web.archive.org/web/20120707000649/http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/basix.html

Answer (score 28):

```latex
\def\K#1#2{#2}

\def\S#1#2#3{#1#3{#2#3}}
```

Comment: finally somebody that makes sense

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: @URL It shows that the [Turing complete S and K combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) can be expressed in LaTeX.

Answer (score 13):

The `pgfmath` library still amazes me. But on a more Turing-related note: it is possible to write an actual Turing machine in TeX, as per [http://en.literateprograms.org/Turing_machine_simulator_(LaTeX)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160110102145/http://en.literateprograms.org/Turing_machine_simulator_%28LaTeX%29). It's just a nifty way of using expansions in TeX.

PostScript is Turing complete as well, if you'll read [the manual](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) you'll be amazed by the general programming capabilities of it (at least, I was).

Comment: People have written LISP in PostScript. (Read the previous sentence until you have fully grasped the strange beauty of such a construction).

Comment: The PLRM manual mentioned is now a dead link, try this instead http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf‎

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as *programming* per se, but I've recently starting doing something a bit like Object Oriented stuff in LaTeX.  (You don't need to know any maths to follow the following.)  In recent papers, I've been writing about *categories*, which have *objects* and *morphisms*.  Since there've been quite a few of those, I wanted a consistent style so that, say, 𝒞 was a category with typical object *C* and typical morphism *c*.  Then I'd also have 𝒟 with *D* and *d*.  So I define a "class", say "category" (you need to be a mathematician to understand the joke there), and declare that C is an instance of this class, and then have access to \ccat, \cobj, \cmor and so forth.  The reason for not doing \cat{c}, \obj{c}, and \mor{c}, and so forth, is that sometimes these categories have special names and so after declaring the instance, I can modify it's name very easily (simply redefine \ccat - well, actually \mathccat since \ccat is a wrapper which selects \mathccat in math mode and \textccat in text mode).  (Of course, it's a little more complicated than the above suggests and the OO stuff really comes in useful when I want to define a new category as a variant of an old one (it can even deal with the case where the old one doesn't exist yet.).)

Although it may not qualify as actual programming, I am using it in papers and do find it useful - the other answers (so far) have more of the feel of showing off the capabilities of LaTeX than of a sensible solution to a practical problem.

Comment: Would love to see how you're doing this!

Answer (score 4):

I know of someone who wrote the answer to [an ACM contest problem](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/ACM/Problems/Spring08/week0/roman.pdf) in LaTeX.

Comment: Hm... unfortunately, I don't have the code lying around, and I've fallen out of touch with the person who wrote it. :/