# Looking for languages that are not Turing complete

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines, turing-complete

I know a little about what is a [turing-machine](/questions/tagged/turing-machine) and a [turing-complete](/questions/tagged/turing-complete) language, but to understand better, could someone give examples of languages that are not Turing complete? (maybe even machines that are not Turing, as well?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regular expressions, in the formal definition, consisting only of:

- concatenation ( ab )
- unbounded repetition ( a* )
- alternation ( a|b )
- grouping ( (ab)|(cd) )

can only recognise regular languages. A Turing-complete programming language can recognise recursively-enumerable languages.

An example is that regular expressions cannot tell you if a string consists of matched pairs of parentheses: eg `()(())` is accepted while `()((())()` is rejected, while Turing-complete programming languages can.

(Note that regexes in modern programming languages are more powerful than the formal academic definition of regular expressions. Some may even be Turing complete.)

Comment: For example, the Perl regexp can be recursive: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/recursive-regular-expressions PHP regexp has the /e flag to evaluate PHP expressions in the subsitution.

Comment: Once saw a regular expression in Perl that matched strings with a length that was a prime number only.  Used backtracking and took quite a while...

Answer (score 3):

[Regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) - those that can be described as regular expressions - are [not Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness#Non-Turing-complete_languages).

Markup languages (used for describing data, not computation) like XML and JSON are not Turing complete.

Comment: The difference between data and computation is tricky. [LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968411/ive-heard-that-latex-is-turing-complete-are-there-any-programs-written-in-latex) is Turing-complete, despite being a text-processing language.

Comment: @Phillip: Not entirely fair, since LaTeX has access to all of TeX which is intended (at least in part) to be a general-purpose language.  See Knuth's page, where he answers the question "What is your favorite language?".